# How to check if lat , long is inside my geofence lat,long,radius

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-api-3, android-geofence

I'm trying to make a circular geofence inside a city, I want this geofence to be 2km circular wide and I want to know if a user is inside this geofence

What I have done

```
 private fun checkIfInsideGeoFence(){
        geofenceList.add(Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId("New York")

                // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                .setCircularRegion(
                    40.6882657,
                    -73.9398756,
                    2000F)

                // Create the geofence.
                .build())

        geofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(),geofencePendingIntent).addOnSuccessListener {
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->

                    // Got last known location, here I need to check if its inside the geofence
                }
        }.addOnFailureListener{

        }

    }

    private fun getGeofencingRequest(): GeofencingRequest {
        return GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
            setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            addGeofences(geofenceList)
        }.build()
    }

    private val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        //Here I dont use a brodcast receiver since I dont need to know if the user enters or leaves the area, just if its inside
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

I need to know inside

```
 fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                    .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->

                        // Got last known location, here I need to check if its inside the geofence
                    }
```

How to know if the user is in that specific ratio

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to check the distance between the center lat long to the current lat long and see if the distance is < 2000 mts

```
 fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->

                val results = FloatArray(1)
                Location.distanceBetween(
                    40.6882657,
                    -73.9398756,
                    location!!.latitude,
                    location.longitude,
                    results
                )
                val distanceInMeters = results[0]
                val isWithin2km = distanceInMeters < 2000
                if(isWithin2km){
                    navigateTo()
                }else{
                    startActivity(Intent(this,ActivityGeoFenceError::class.java))
                    finish()
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you have solved the question by yourself already, please consider marking your own answer as correct. It helps the other devs to look into your answer knowing that it solved the problem you had. Thank you!

Comment: @CoffeeBreak can you check my question as well

Answer (score 0):

Based on @CoffeeBreak's approach, one could also use the instance method [`distanceTo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) as well to make it less verbose. Something like this in a form of an extension function:

```
fun Location.checkIsInBound(radius: Int,center:Location):Boolean
        =  this.distanceTo(center)<radius

fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
        val isWithin2km = location?.checkIsInBound(2000,center) }
```

Besides using Location API's [`distanceTo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#distanceTo(android.location.Location)), You could also use Google Map Utility Library's `SphericalUtil`'s [`computeDistanceBetween`](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeDistanceBetween-LatLng-LatLng-) as well, however it takes `LatLng` as input.

Comment: can you check my post as well